# How to return a 410 code for previously published posts now set to draft?

Tags: redirect, post-status

I'd like to return a 410 code for posts (of custom type "news") which have previously been published (and therefore have a url indexed by search engines), but have now had the post status set to draft.

Here's my attempt:

```
function news_gone() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular( 'news' ) && get_post_status($post->id) == "draft"  ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(410);
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'news_gone' );
```

This, however, has no effect - is `template_redirect` the correct hook, or is there a better approach?

Comment: if the post is set to draft then it could not possibly be `$post` because the main query does not include draft posts, so your post status check will never match. For it to work it would need to find a post that has the status of publish or private that also has the status of draft, which is a paradox/contradiction and impossible. Instead it's more likely to find a 404 because no published post was found on that URL

Comment: Thank you - hadn't considered this... I've now set the post status to `private` and works as expected.

Comment: Update - setting to `private` only works for logged in users.

Comment: indeed, this filter will never work the way you intend it, the approach is a dead end as `is_singular` is always false and `get_post_status` is never `draft` here. In the situation you are trying to check for it will always be a 404 that found no posts